# The 'getAccountInfo' function return null

Tags: solana

I'm using QuickNode for my Solana blockchain transactions, but I have a point I want to understand.

```js
const recipientInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(recipient);
if (!recipientInfo) throw new CreateTransferError('recipient not found');
```

Sometimes the getAccountInfo variable turns out to be null, and some of my users receive a 'recipient not found' error when making SPL-token transfers. Could this be related to the RPC service?

Answer (score 0):

If the account is not found, then there are a few possibilities:

- the account truly doesn't exist, so the error is correct
- the RPC node is behind the current state, but you may receive another error before getting `null`
- the most likely reason: the account exists, but it was *just* created, and the creation hasn't been confirmed on the network yet. Typically, you can just try to fetch again and it'll be there.